# Vertex Array for Star OpenGL

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I want to draw a star using Open GL on iPhone. Can anyone share me the Vertex Array and Indices Array

Comment: It is interesting that suddenly there have been other questions about drawing stars in the last week. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the x,y locations of the five points by taking the sin and cos of the five angles. The five angles are 360 degrees divided by the five points.

If you provide your code attempt I suspect there will be helpful answers.